# CSS3 media queries with separate css files

Tags: css, media-queries

**I would like to create a different CSS file specific for mobile devices.** I've been able to detect if the device is a mobile, but, only if I have all the styles defined in the same file with the @media statements.

**I would prefer to have the files separated, and that I haven't been able to achieve and would like you to tell me how.**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/combined.css" media="screen" />
```

combined.css: (this works, but all styles are in the same CSS file)

```
// for desktop browsers
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    h1 { text-decoration: none; }
}

// for mobile devices
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    h1 { text-decoration: underline; }
}
```

When I try to seperate them...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

desktop.css:

```
h1 { text-decoration: none; }
```

mobile.css:

```
h1 { text-decoration: underline; }
```

... it doesn't work anymore. **Why?** How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

How are you detecting if the device is Mobile or Not? Are you using PHP?

If this is the case then you can easily include just the correct file based on your is_mobile flag.

```
<?php if(!$is_mobile) { ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am using CSS3 media queries to detect it, which I think it's the good practice way to do it. That's explained in my question above. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. What happens if you wrap the individual files in the media queries?
The benefit of detecting mobile or not on the server side is that the user only has to download one file, opposed to both. With most mobiles being slow and more restricted than most desktops this would be preferred to speed things along.